# Why is there an intermediate redirect to https://public-url.org/wp-admin?

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, ssl

I have the SITE_DOMAIN set as foo.example.**com**, this has a SSL for `*.example.com`

`http://example.org`, is the url for the frontpage, this works. There is no certificate for `example.org`. Now, when I access `http://example.org/wp-admin` the following happens:

1. Redirect from  http://example.org/wp-admin to https://example.org/wp-admin
2. Client (browser) issues a certificate warning, there is no certificate for `example.org`.
3. Client must make an exception for the certificate.
4. Redirected from  https://example.org/wp-admin to https://foo.example.com/wp-login.php

Is this intended behaviour? Why does WP make an intermediate redirect to https://example.org/wp-admin? Is this a known bug, and if so, what would be the bug-number?

Comment: I'm confused. If SITE_DOMAIN is foo.example.com, why are you trying to hit example.com/wp-admin -- wouldn't you be accessing via foo.example.com/wp-admin?